# Powershell Pass Variable to Function with SQL Query Loop and IN Clause

Tags: powershell, variables, parameter-passing, sqlclient

What I like to do is pass the $sContractNumbers variable to the loop I have below which essentially pieces two csv files together based on the SQL queries.

I'm using the block below to get a value from an excel spreadsheet. Something that will be updated by a different user. The cell will always be static but the data in the cell will change in size so I have to use the IN clause.

My variable value looks like so.

> $sContractNumbers = 'abc123','abc456','abc789','abc112','abc345'

```
    $xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
    $xl.Visible = $true
    $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dev\Blah\ManualContracts.xlsx")
    $ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)
    #Looking up a value in one column and assigning the corresponding value from another column to a variable could be done like this:
    
    for ($i = 0; $i -le 1; $i++) {
      if ( $ws.Cells.Item(1, 2).Text -eq $ColumnHeader ) {
        $i = $i++;
        $sContractNumbers = $ws.Cells.Item(2, 2).Value
        #$sContractNumber
        break
      }
    }
    
    $wb.Close()
    $xl.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
    
    $sContractNumbers
```

Prior to adding this piece I was just copying and pasting my list of contracts in both queries.

Currently the error I'm getting is the following. I don't believe the loop is picking up on the variable. I've tried using AddWithValue but I don't think I'm placing it correctly, which is why its not listed. Fairly new to powershell but know a little bit of T-SQL. I think its a simple question but I cannot fully understand what I need to correct it since I'm noob. Be gentle...

```
    $DetailContent[1] = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $HeadeDetail, $DetailContent[1]
         |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         | Cannot index into a null array.
```

```
    Function Run-Query
    {
        param([string[]]$queries,[string[]]$sheetnames)
        Begin
        {
            $SQLServer = 'server'
            $Database = 'warehouse'
            $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"
            $FileNameDate = Get-Date -f 'yyyyMMdd'
        }#End Begin
        Process
        {
            # Loop through each query
            For($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.count; $i++)
            {
                $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                $SqlCmd.CommandText = $queries[$i]
                $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
                $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
                $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Dev\blah\HeaderDetail\$($sheetnames[$i])_$FileNameDate-000.csv" -Delimiter '|'
                
            }
        }#End Process
        End
        {
            $SqlConnection.Close()
        }
    }#End function run-query.
    
    $queries = @()
    
    $queries += @'
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    /*FE Header*/
      SELECT [sContractNumber] as ContractNumber,
      into #Temp
      FROM  C
      INNER JOIN  D ON C.Id=D.iId
      WHERE c.sContractNumber in ('$sContractNumbers')
      order by sContractNumber
    
    declare @TotalNewContracts int = 0
    declare @TotalCanContracts int = 0
    declare @TotalExpContracts int = 0
    
    set @TotalNewContracts = (select COUNT(fe.ContractNumber) from #temp fe where Record_Type = 'P')
    set @TotalCanContracts = (select COUNT(fe.ContractNumber) from #temp fe where Record_Type = 'C')
    
    select
    count(contractnumber) as 'Total Number of All Contracts',
    FROM #temp ;
    
    drop table #Temp;
    '@
    
    $queries += @'
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    
    /*FE Header*/
      SELECT [sContractNumber] as ContractNumber,
      into #Table
      FROM [pcmi_warranty_custom_twsi].[dbo].[Contract_Header] C
      INNER JOIN [pcmi_warranty_custom_twsi].[dbo].[Dealer_Header] D ON C.iDealerId=D.iId
      WHERE c.sContractNumber in ('$sContractNumbers')
      order by sContractNumber
    
    SELECT ContractNumber,
    FROM #temp FE;
    
    drop table #Temp;
    '@
    
    $sheetnames = @()
    $sheetnames += 'Header'
    $sheetnames += 'Details'
    
    #FileName
    $FileNameDate = Get-Date -f 'yyyyMMdd'
    Run-Query -queries $queries -sheetnames $sheetnames
    #Removes Double Quotes from File
    (Get-Content C:\Dev\blah\HeaderDetail\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ''} | out-file -FilePath C:\Dev\blah\Header\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
    (Get-Content C:\Dev\blah\HeaderDetail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ''} | out-file -FilePath C:\Dev\blah\Detail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
    #Add Double Pipes as Delimter
    (Get-Content C:\Dev\blah\Header\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv) | % {$_ -replace "\|", "||"} | out-file -FilePath C:\Dev\blah\Header\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
    (Get-Content C:\Dev\blah\Detail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv) | % {$_ -replace "\|", "||"} | out-file -FilePath C:\Dev\blah\Detail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
    #Add Header Detail Row to Detail File
    #Header Path
    $HeaderPath = "C:\Dev\blah\Header\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv"
    #Detail Path
    $DetailsPath = "C:\Dev\blah\Detail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv"
    #Gets second row of header file and sets it as a varaible
    $HeadeDetail = Get-Content $HeaderPath -TotalCount 2 | Select-Object -Last 1;
    #print the header detail row
    $HeadeDetail
    #Get Detail File content
    $DetailContent = Get-Content -Path $DetailsPath
    #Add Header Detail row to Detail file
    $DetailContent[1] = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $HeadeDetail, $DetailContent[1] 
    #Save Detail File
    $DetailContent | Set-Content "C:\Dev\blah\blah$FileNameDate-000.csv" -Force -Encoding ascii
    #Set the file name
    $SourceFile = "C:\Dev\blah\blah$FileNameDate-000.csv"
    $DestinationFolder = 'C:\Dev\blah'
    $HeaderFile = "C:\Dev\blah\Header\Header_$FileNameDate-000.csv"
    $DetailFile = "C:\Dev\blah\Detail\Details_$FileNameDate-000.csv"
    $HDestinationFolder = 'C:\Dev\blah\Header'
    $DDestinationFolder = 'C:\Dev\blah\Detail'
    
    if (Test-Path $SourceFile)
    { 
        $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationFolder| Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        #split the latest filename, increment the number, then re-assemble new filename:
        $newFileName = $latest.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + "-" + ([int]$latest.BaseName.Split('-')[1] + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3,"0") + $latest.Extension
        Move-Item -path $SourceFile -destination $DestinationFolder"\"$newFileName
    }
    if (Test-Path $HeaderFile)
    { 
        $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $HDestinationFolder| Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        #split the latest filename, increment the number, then re-assemble new filename:
        $newFileName = $latest.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + "-" + ([int]$latest.BaseName.Split('-')[1] + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3,"0") + $latest.Extension
        Move-Item -path $HeaderFile -destination $HDestinationFolder"\"$newFileName
    }
    if (Test-Path $DetailFile)
    { 
        $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $DDestinationFolder| Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        #split the latest filename, increment the number, then re-assemble new filename:
        $newFileName = $latest.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + "-" + ([int]$latest.BaseName.Split('-')[1] + 1).ToString().PadLeft(3,"0") + $latest.Extension
        Move-Item -path $DetailFile -destination $DDestinationFolder"\"$newFileName
    }
    
    #Creates backup folder with corresponding date and places the file
    $FolderName = Get-Date -f 'MMdd'
    $FolderToCreate = "C:\Dev\blah\$FolderName"
    if (!(Test-Path $FolderToCreate -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $FolderToCreate
    }
    Copy-Item -Path "$DestinationFolder\TWFE*.csv" -Destination $FoldertoCreate -force; 
    
    $ODrive = 'O:\blah\blah\blah'
    $FolderToCopy = "O:\blah\blah\blah\$FolderName"
    $LatestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$DestinationFolder\$FolderName" -Name TWFE*.csv | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    if (!(Test-Path $FolderToCopy -PathType Container)) {
        Copy-Item -Path "$DestinationFolder\$FolderName" -Destination $FolderToCopy -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Continue
    }
    
    if ((Test-Path $FolderToCopy -PathType Container)) {
        Copy-Item -Path $LatestFile -Destination $FolderToCopy -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Continue
    }
```

Comment: That’s... a lot of code. Your first task might be to split it into functions that you can test independently in order to isolate where the problem is. One thing to try as a shot-to-nothing is ```write-host``` your sql queries as you execute them and make sure they’re doing what you expect them to...

Comment: I was thinking of making the sql scripts SP and use the ExcuteStoreproc method which I can feed params. still not sure it it will fix my problem but willl start there. Thanks for the tip